# Intel i7 Core CPU numbers on the front side

Tags: cpu, intel, serial-number

What is the numer at the fourth row on the front side of Intel i7 CPU? (pictured)

[image]

I saw two Intel CPUs in the store described as "Core i7-6700" but have slightly different prices (both OEMs). Only the difference I found is the numbers on the front side.

P.S. I'm already guessing it is kind of a serial number but not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the Finished Process Order serial number, and is essentially a lot number. It is used by Intel to determine warranty information.

[Source 1](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/specification-updates/desktop-6th-gen-core-family-spec-update.pdf)

[Source 2](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/processors/000005609.html)

Comment: Could you please also explain what is the number on 3rd line? Thank you!

Comment: Other than the "SSPEC", which is what the first source says?

Comment: I got it, Just first source is temporarily unavailable.

Comment: Btw, it is temporarily unavailable in IE browser) Thanks!

Comment: Try [here](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/core/desktop-6th-gen-core-family-spec-update.html) then.